# iptables on DD-wrt to bypass VPN outgoing port 993

Tags: vpn, openvpn, iptables, dd-wrt

I'm using the DD-wrt, openVPN client and NordVPN.

I recently found out NordVPN blocks Email ports like secure Imap port 993.
Ive been trying to create a rule in my DD-wrt commands, and i can't seem to get it right.
I'd like to allow all outgoing 993 ports to bypass the VPN.

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter  
iptables -t mangle -F PREROUTING  
ip route add default table 200 via $(nvram get wan_gateway)  
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 200  
ip route flush cache
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i br0 -s 192.168.0.150 -j MARK --set-mark 1            #never use VPn for this IP
#iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j MARK --set-mark 1                    #<--didn't work
#iptables -I OUTPUT -m tcp -p tcp -m multiport --dports 993,465 -j MARK --set-mark 1     #<--didn't work 
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 993,465 -j MARK --set-mark 1   #<-didn't work
```

What am i missing. Am i even getting close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're close, but you need to put 'set-mark' in the `PREROUTING` chain in *all* cases – it doesn't make sense to put it in the OUTPUT chain.

(The `OUTPUT` chain is only used for traffic that's generated *on the same system* – in other words it'll only affect connections done by DD-WRT, not those forwarded through DD-WRT.)

---

If your router had a newer Linux kernel (and newer iproute2), you wouldn't need fwmark – you could directly create policy rules which match on the layer-4 port:

```
ip rule add dport 993 table 200
```

Comment: I changed the last rule OUTPUT to PREROUTING and that made it work. thank you so much!